# Enable Remote Desktop for the whole PC

Tags: remote-desktop, vino

How can I set up my PC the Remote Desktop is enabled from the moment it is booted, regardless of who is logged on?

Currently, I have to open vino-preferences so I can access my PC from another computer.  But if my wife then logs on, I can't see either my account or my wife's.

Can it be set up as a service, so it is enabled when I turn on the computer?

Comment: Sry i don't understand `But if my wife then logs on, I can't see either my account or my wife's.` What do you mean with account?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are talking about Ubuntu's built in VNC service, (when you say remote deskop I always think Windows RDP,) You need to look at your setting at

**System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop**

There you should see all the settings you need.  This ofcourse just shares access to the computer so two users cannot log into two different accounts,  you can share mouse control or one can watch though.

Also this link may be of help:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Answer (score 3):

Dump `vino`. Its only job is to share the currently open session which means you can't do what you want.

There are a couple of alternatives to VNC but I'll start with another VNC solution first. TightVNC is another open source server that, with a bit of kicking, lets you pipe a whole new GDM screen through VNC, effectively allowing you to login as who you want.

The downside to this is you don't get to remote-control apps running on the real computer screen as when you login to this, you'll get a brand new desktop session. You might just want to control whoever's logged in so this wouldn't be for you.

[Unfortunately the only tutorial I've* been able to find is for Gentoo](http://linuxreviews.org/howtos/xvnc/) (another linux distribution).

*And when I say "I've", I mean `xiaclo` on `#ubuntu`. *I* couldn't find any tutorials.

---

If you do just want to control whoever's logged in but hate having to configure VNC, I use `x11vnc` over ssh from my phone (it's a linux phone). Here's the one command I fire off:

```
ssh oli@192.168.0.4 -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc" | vncviewer
```

This tunnels the VNC server's connection back over the SSH to a local port so you connect from your client to localhost:5900. The  `| vncviewer` bit just opens the VNC client at the same time. That might be specific to my phone, so you might need to change that to whatever VNC viewer you use.

---

#### NoMachine/FreeNX

There are other options perhaps better suited to the task. NoMachine/NX/FreeNX/etc are RDP-style servers that allow logins but they need a NX client. The benefit over VNC is it's *really* fast and quite low-bandwidth.

The [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) should get you started but I'll warn you, it's not a short journey.